# Accessing struct from an externally called function

Tags: rust

Preface: I have some experience in Rust but not very much, so it's possible there's a trivial solution to my problem. Specifically, I'm still not very good with the way Rust handles memory even though I understand the basic concept.

Anyway, I'm using an external crate (winapi, to be precise, but more on that later), which places some restrictions on what I'm trying to do. Here are the facts:

- I need to call the crate to create something, to which I am then provided a handle.
- I want to store the handle, along with other relevant data, in a struct.
- The crate also wants a callback, which it then calls frequently.
- One of the parameters of the callback function called by the crate is the handle.
- In the callback function, I'd also like to access my own data stored in the struct along with the handle, so I need to be able to be able to somehow get the struct *from* the handle.
- The crate provides no good way to provide a reference to my struct to the callback function. As a result, I'm storing a global handle-struct hash map, but this isn't working as I'm hoping.

Here's some code to roughly demonstrate my problem:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::collections::HashMap;

thread_local!(static WRAPPER_LIST_CELL: RefCell<HashMap<u32, usize>> = RefCell::new(HashMap::new()));

static mut MAX_ID: u32 = 0;

struct Data {
    x: i32
}

fn main() {
    let data = Data { x: 17 };
    let wrapper= create_wrapper(data);
    // For all intents and purposes, do_something below is actually called by
    // the external crate in a loop. This ought to demonstrate the problem
    // well enough though.
    do_something(wrapper.id);
}

struct Wrapper {
    id: u32,
    data: Data,
}

impl Wrapper {
    fn new(data: Data) -> Wrapper {
        // This is the function that would actually call the crate to
        // create the 'something' I need.
        unsafe {
            // No ID is actually needed when using the crate. The crate
            // provides a unique handle instead, which works largely to
            // the same effect as the ID here.
            let id = MAX_ID;
            MAX_ID += 1;
            let wrapper = Wrapper { id: id, data: data };
            WRAPPER_LIST_CELL.with(|cell| {
                let mut list = cell.borrow_mut();
                list.insert(wrapper.id, &wrapper as *const Wrapper as usize);
            });
            wrapper
        }
    }
}

fn create_wrapper(data: Data) -> Wrapper {
    Wrapper::new(data)
}

fn do_something(id: u32) {
    unsafe {
        WRAPPER_LIST_CELL.with(|cell| {
            let list_ptr = cell.as_ptr();
            let list_ptr = (*view_list_ptr)[&id] as *const Wrapper;
            println!("do_something: {}", (*list_ptr).data.x); // not 17
        });
    }
}
```

For the most part, everything seems fine. *However*, when trying to access my struct in do_something, I notice its address is different from what it is in main. This results in me trying to access the wrong location in memory, which is probably the reason the program crashes.

The crate *does* provide a way to freely store and access a pointer to custom data, e.g. my struct, but it takes the pointer essentially as an isize, i.e. the memory address of my struct, which, again, changes between main and do_something. That is, it doesn't seem like it can really be used.

As mentioned, the crate I'm using is winapi, i.e. Rust bindings for the Windows API. In case it's relevant, I get (window) handles using CreateWindowExW and do_something is more or less WindowProc. For ease of use, I want to wrap the window handle along with my own window data in a Window struct. There are things I need to do in WindowProc that require me to access my own window data. I have provided a simplified version of my actual code because the problem itself seems like it could appear in other situations as well, and because using the Windows API is quite messy and not at all relevant to the question. If requested, I can provide actual code using the Windows API however.

Finally the actual question: **What can I do to resolve my problem, i.e. wrap things nicely in a struct and have everything work?** I imagine being able to store actual references in the global variable would help, but that doesn't seem to be possible unless I'm missing something.

Comment: The reason why the addresses change is because your `wrapper` is moved when it is returned from `create_wrapper`. You want to box it an use [`Pin`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/pin/index.html) to ensure that even though the box is moved, the `Wrapper` itself isn't.

Comment: @Jmb: Well that was exactly the trivial solution I was half-expecting and didn't even know about! It took me a while to get the pointers pointing where I want (i.e. to my actual data instead of its Pin), but it was a good learning experience and finally things are working. Thanks a lot!